# recursive batch rename files

Tags: macos, command-line, batch-rename

I have audio library that has artworks in every folder and the names are: Cover.PNG, Cover.png, Cover.JPEG, Cover.jpeg, Cover.JPG, Cover.jpg…

How to recursively find all those files and rename them all to cover.png, cover.jpg?

Looking for command line way to do it.

Comment: your question is not limited to a specific osx version so you didnt tag it well. I have improved your tags.  And you should google. I'm sure the linux solution will apply as many commands are the same or very similar.

Comment: Thank you for help! I've already tried multiple ways with `find` and `rename` pipes and it didn't work at all((( That's why I'm asking here

Comment: well if you did all that research, you should list what you tried and where/why it didn't work, it may be interesting for people, and it may also provide some of the work towards the solution and spur somebody to find a good or some good answers that actually do work..  And it may enable somebody to address what you tried, and enhance your understanding, as well as that of others..

Comment: It might also prevent anyone else wasting half an hour posting a GUI-based answer :(

Comment: @Tetsujin, I've bumped your answer so you've got your score anyways

Answer (score 6):

*Posted before the command line addendum*

Assuming you can get them all in a single path, then you can do it in 3 passes using the Finder's own Rename utility.

Using a small example set, variations of cover.png, open the top level of your hierarchy in list view.
Option/click the top level will open the entire hierarchy inside it…
*(I made this pic last, as I forgot to include this step)*

[image]

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>  to select all

[image]

Right click the selection & in the drop menu, select Rename *nnn* Items

[image]

[image]

In the window that opens, select Replace Text, then type your existing case-**in**sensitive name.
Type a Case-sensitive replacement [first time use png, 2nd use jpg - you'll probably need a third pass to pick up strays like jpeg]
Hit Rename.

[image]

Repeat for jpg & jpeg.
You don't need to change your selection as it will only change matching names.

It's probably quicker to do 3 passes like this than it is to set up complex rename rules in a 'smarter' app.

Comment: There is no "Rename" option in drop menu > Services

Comment: Sorry, it's right there in the main right-click menu. My machine still has a hangover from a previous renamer app too. Updating answer..

Comment: This is not a great solution for the depressing reason that Finder is terrible at the task of handling a huge number of files. If you want to rename every file on a disk of ~100,000+ files, Finder will hang early in this process, while attempting to perform the option-click to recursively open each directory. 
Kinda amazing that obvious bugs like this STILL exist, but that's the Finder team for you...

Answer (score 2):

I needed to rename various image files to be named "cover.jpg" so the artork would show up in Sonos. Basically, I needed to run:
mv *.jpg cover.jpg
in every subdirectory

This was what did just that:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -execdir mv {} cover.jpg \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable at the command line, open terminal:

```
Application -> Utilities -> Terminal
```

Then run a command like this:

```
find . -type f -name Cover.jpg -execdir mv {} cover.jpg \;
```

Where:

```
find . -type f -name <old> -execdir mv {} <new_name> \;
```

Do this for each file you want to rename.

Comment: I have different extensions as well… Can I use a wildcard (for example `Cover.*) with this command? Getting this so far: `zsh: no matches found: cover.*` Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, was my bad... Done it like you said and noticed strange thing about this method. For some reason it doesn't change the upper case to lower and doesn't change .jpeg to .jpg

Comment: Spell out the <old> with the exact case and extension as it is before the change.  Spell out <new_name> with the exact case and extension as you want the new one to be.  Edit and run it for each file name you are trying to change.  I've tested it, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are some applications that can help you in this regard. NameChanger is free, and the following are paid: Renamer, File Renamer, Rename It.

If you have a Windows machine, there's a wonderful free tool I use personally, called Bulk Rename Utility. It seems complex and outdated on first look but is very powerful and super easy to use.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. Provide at least a link, as well as some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I forgot to mention, that I'm looking for command line way to do it (edited my post)

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry about that, I'm new here. Will definitely go through the recommendation rules and keep em in mind next time, thanks!

Comment: NameChanger does not handle recursion!